# Binding value to input in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have input like this

```
<input type="text" name="widget.title" ng-model="widget.title" value="{{widget.title}}"/>
```

I want to change input value dynamically so i use that but it doesn't change the value:

```
$scope.widget.title = 'a';
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You don't need to set the value at all. ng-model takes care of it all:

- set the input value from the model
- update the model value when you change the input
- update the input value when you change the model from js

Here's the fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/terebentina/9mFpp/

Answer (score 18):

If you don't wan't to use ng-model there is `ng-value` you can try.

Here's the fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/Rg9sG/1/

Comment: On the fiddle anyway, this seems to only work if the value in the input field has never been changed.

Comment: I have the same problem, I cannot change the value from the controller

Comment: Only works for setting the value, but won't update the scope variable after the user changed the input: "It can also be used to achieve one-way binding" (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue)

Comment: This was an awesome solution for my datepickers.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ng-value` for set value of input box after clicking on a `button`:

```
"input type="email"  class="form-control" id="email2" ng-value="myForm.email2" placeholder="Email"
```

and

Set Value as:

```
 $scope.myForm.email2 = $scope.names[0].success;
```

Answer (score -1):

Some times there are problems with funtion/features that do not interact with the DOM

try to change the value sharply and then assign the $scope

```
document.getElementById ("textWidget") value = "<NewVal>";
$scope.widget.title = "<NewVal>";
```

Answer (score -6):

`{{widget.title}}` 
Try this it will work