# Binding value to select in angular js across 2 controllers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, angularjs

Working with angularJS I am trying to figure out a way to bind the value of a select element under the scope of controller A to use it as an argument for an ng-click call [getQuizByCampID() Function] under the scope of controller B.

My first idea was to use jquery, but I have read in the link below that using jquery is not recommended when starting with angularJS.

["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

I also read in the link below that this is performed using ng-model, the only problem is that that the example provided is all under the same controller. 
  and [Binding value to input in Angular JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421979/binding-value-to-input-in-angular-js)

What is the angularJS way to get the value of the select element under controller A into the function call in the select under controller B?

### Price.html view

```
  <div class="col-sm-3" ng-controller="campCtrl"> **Controller A** 
       <select  id="selCampID" class="form-control" ng-model="campInput" >
            <option ng-repeat="camp in campaigns" value="{{camp.camp_id}}">{{camp.camp_name}}</option>  
        </select>
  </div>

   <div class="col-sm-3" ng-controller="quizCtrl">  **Controller B**
        <select   ng-click="getQuizByCampID($('#selCampID').val())" class="form-control" ng-model="quizInput">
             <option ng-controller="quizCtrl" ng-repeat="quiz in quizzesById" value="{{quiz.quiz_id}}">{{quiz.quiz_name}}</option>  
         </select>
    </div>
```

### App.js

```
var app= angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/price', {templateUrl: 'partials/price.html', controller: 'priceCtrl'});
}]);

$routeProvider.when('/price', {templateUrl: 'partials/price.html', controller: 'priceCtrl'});
```

### Quiz Controller

```
'use strict';

app.controller('quizCtrl', ['$scope','$http','loginService', function($scope,$http,loginService){
$scope.txt='Quiz';
$scope.logout=function(){
    loginService.logout();
}
getQuiz(); // Load all available campaigns 
function getQuiz(campID){  
    $http.post("js/ajax/getQuiz.php").success(function(data){
    $scope.quizzes = data;
    //console.log(data);
   });
};
  $scope.getQuizByCampID = function (campid) {
  alert(campid);
$http.post("js/ajax/getQuiz.php?campid="+campid).success(function(data){
    $scope.quizzesById = data;
    $scope.QuizInput = "";
  });
  };

    $scope.addQuiz = function (quizid, quizname, campid) { 
  console.log(quizid + quizname + campid);   
  $http.post("js/ajax/addQuiz.php?quizid="+quizid+"&quizname="+quizname+"&campid="+campid).success(function(data){

  getQuiz();
  $scope.QuizInput = "";
});
  };

}])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store the value in a service.

example:

```
app.factory('SharedService', function() {
  this.inputValue = null;

  this.setInputValue = function(value) {
    this.inputValue = value;
  }

  this.getInputValue = function() {
    return this.inputValue;
  }

  return this;
});
```

[Example on Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/DpzOnw2EuuzuGVeRbEVu?p=preview)

Read: [AngularJS Docs on services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)

or check this [Egghead.io video](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-sharing-data-between-controllers)

Answer (score 0):

You should use service to store the value.

This is how to do that:
[Share data between AngularJS controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/angular-share-data-between-controllers)