# angularjs http get data, put field type date into html5 input date

Tags: angularjs, html

I'm getting json data from api, I have a field called PURCHASEDATE with type: Date in mysql.

I made an http request and got all the data.

html:

```
<input type="date" ng-model="purchaseDate">
```

js:

```
//get function
$scope.purchaseDate=row.PURCHASEDATE;
```

I tried to alert and console log, everything is ok, I got the date : 2017-01-16

I tried to print the input value in html `@{{purchaseDate}}` and it's printing 2017-01-16.

the problem is that the date is not filling in the html input date. Any idea?

Comment: did you try to put it in the value?

Comment: $scope.purchaseDate=row.PURCHASEDATE; the ngmodel is filling with the value, but the input not showing the date

Comment: <input type="date" ng-model="purchaseDate" value="@{{purchaseDate}}">

Comment: yes I tried that, not working

Comment: tried removing @?

Comment: I can't, working with blades

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610282/angularjs-value-attribute-on-an-input-text-box-is-ignored-when-there-is-a-ng-m?answertab=active#tab-top
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421979/binding-value-to-input-in-angular-js?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: working now, I tried $scope.purchaseDate=new Date(row.PURCHASEDATE); thank you

Answer (score 0):

working fine, the solution is, when I get the data, I used :

$scope.purchaseDate= new Date(row.PURCHASEDATE);

thank you